# Transfer to other server

Tags: magento2, database, media, code, transfer

I want to transfer to other server my store (new server have plesk panel ).

I wrote command in cli

```
bin/magento setup:backup --code --media --db
```

from old server with this method can i take those backups and reinstall magento  from start and put those backups again?
It will be fine will be all work fine?

Comment: As  per as,  my personal view , instead of taking  magento  backup using command line.. you have to take  gerenal backup process mean zip/tar the file and dump the database

Comment: So I have to take full backup of www/html?  And dba?

Comment: yes. it is  better idea

Comment: well its about 47gb all this :S

Comment: As it is a new installation you can take backup of customized  functionalities like app/code and any design if you have overrides or any libraries added, the vendor foder is not required as it was default on fresh installation